# Android app crashes, due to count down timer?

Tags: java, android, timer, crash

I have made an app recently and I added a count down timer one day and made a few changes here and there and now when I run the app on my (actual) Galaxy Note 3 it crashes as soon as I hit the Play button below are my LevelOne.java file and my MainActivity.Java file. By the way the logcat shows nothing as if it doesn't realize it crashed.

LevelOne.java

```
package com.parker.orangedot;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LevelOne extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button myButton;
    LevelOne context;
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500)
    {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Scores.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);

        //ass soon as this activity is created, I start my timer.
        timer.start();

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                timer.cancel();
            }});
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
    public void next(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openScores(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Scores.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.level_one, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.parker.orangedot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public void openScores(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Scores.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void play(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelOne.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

***UPDATE:***

When using the emulater for the Galaxy Nexus, pressing "play" does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Did you add an `activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest` for `LevelOne`?

Comment: please take a look at the logcat

Comment: `context` is obviously null. replace by `LevelOne.this`. And fix your logcat, there is an exception here.

Comment: @adneal Yes. (extra words so I can post this comment)